# resignFirstResponder when tapping UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with two custom cells and each of them has a subview with a `UITextField` inside it. I have tried adding a `UIButton` on top of the `UITableView` and have it `resignFirstResponder` but that just means you won't be able to tap anywhere else - not even on the `UITextFields` to enter text.

How do I make it so if I tap outside those two `UITextFields`, I can call resignFirstResponder, so the user can get back to the other cells?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450127/how-can-i-tell-when-something-outside-my-uitableviewcell-has-been-touched) and [found an answer myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450127/how-can-i-tell-when-something-outside-my-uitableviewcell-has-been-touched/2452049#2452049) which I posted.  Basically you can override hitTest:withEvent: in your custom UITableViewCell which lets you detect when a touch occurred in your cell or any other cell that is in the table view.  I provided an example hitTest: method that duplicates the functionality of the original hitTest: and you can just add what you need to it.  You can add your resignFirstResponder inside the hitTest function like I did or customize it further.

Answer (score 2):

A nice simple way to do it would be to subclass a UITableView and implement the touch methods (not forgetting to pass them to the super afterwards!). From in there you can inspect a touch in touches began and decide whether it's a touch that's inside the UITextField (using the hitTest: method in UIView). If the hitTest does not return a UITextField you can call a method in your controller to resign the first responder. Hope this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying to tap outside of the field to resign first responder, just resize your tableview with -setFrame when the keyboard displays so that it is in the visible area above the keyboard. Then you'll be able to scroll the view to the other cells. You can be notified that the keyboard is visible by registering for the event like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then implement keyboardWillShow:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification;
{
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 200.0f)];
}
```

Best Regards.

Comment: I'd really rather be able to resignFirstResponder, because the keyboard lies on top of a TabBar, which the user should be able to go back to, if they want.