# Proper way to resignFirstResponder when a UITableView is touched?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a pretty simple `UITableView` who's cells contain `UITextField`s and I need to be able to call `resignFirstResponder` to hide the keyboard whenever a user touches the UITableView outside of one of the cells.

I have read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450127/how-can-i-tell-when-something-outside-my-uitableviewcell-has-been-touched/2452049#2452049) but it seems like a very rudimentary way to achieve this. I have read about a way to do it by converting the `UITableView` to a `UIControl` so that you can connect the TouchDown event.

Does anybody know the standard or preferred way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tap gesture recognizer will detect taps, however I have sometimes found that it interfered with the normal row selection mechanism. I think I've come up with a good solution in my [answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288516/927947) Where I've posted some example code of a `UIView` subclass that you set as the `accessoryInputView` of the textfield. Then if you select the textfield it adds the tap recognizer automatically, and then automatically removes it when you've finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not doing iPhone dev anymore, but it's nice to know that this was answered properly :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty intresting , but not to very hard, for that you have to use  UITapGestureRecognizer...

### in .h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

### in .m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self 
action:@selector(tableClicked)];
[tableview addGestureRecognizer:tapgesture];

[super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)tableClicked
{

     [txtField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

fallow this example code , i think it works...Thank you..

Comment: This seems to work but in the end it prevents the tableview cells to be selected.