# How to dismiss UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I'm trying to hide the number pad, but I do not want to implement a button.

Is there a way to dismiss the number pad when the user taps outside the textfield?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those questions where you read it and say "That's easy you just..". And then you go to do it and make it super complicated. And then realize it doesn't have to be that complicated.

The answer I've come up with, and I'm sure it will help someone else, Is to use an invisible `UIView` that never interacts but acts on other views and maybe not in the way you'd think.

The typical answer to a question about dismissing the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` keyboard is to add a bar that has a button as the `inputAccessoryView` to dismiss the keyboard. If a bar and button are undesirable generally you just listen for touch events on the background and your good to go but this question is about a tableview and that makes this much harder.

But this `inputAccessoryView` feature is still awesome. It allows you to define a `UIView` or `UIView` subclass to be displayed when the keyboard is shown. More importantly when the keyboard is shown due to a textfield for which it is the `inputAccessoryView` becoming first responder.

I could yammer on but first here is some code for a lightweight class that actually performs very well in testing.

The contents of `NJ_KeyboardDismisser.h` are:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    // For some reason neither inputView or inputAccessoryView are IBOutlets, so we cheat.
@interface UITextField (WhyDoIHaveToDoThisApple)
@property (readwrite, retain) IBOutlet UIView *inputAccessoryView;
@end

@interface NJ_KeyboardDismisser : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
-(id)initWithMainView:(UIView *)view; // convienience method for code
@end
```

And the contents of `NJ_KeyboardDismisser.m` are:

```
#import "NJ_KeyboardDismisser.h"
@implementation NJ_KeyboardDismisser {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *_tapGR;
}
@synthesize mainView = _mainView;
-(void)setMainView:(UIView *)view{
    if (_tapGR) [_tapGR.view removeGestureRecognizer:_tapGR];
    _mainView = view;
    _tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:_mainView action:@selector(endEditing:)];
}
-(id)initWithMainView:(UIView *)view{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)])){
        self.mainView = view;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)didMoveToWindow{ // When the accessory view presents this delegate method will be called
    [super didMoveToWindow];
    if (self.window){ // If there is a window one of the textfields, for which this view is inputAccessoryView, is first responder.
        [self.mainView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGR];
    }
    else { // If there is no window the textfield is no longer first responder
        [self.mainView removeGestureRecognizer:_tapGR];
    }
}
@end
```

You may recognize the `endEditing:` method, as mentioned by Cosique, it is a UIView extension  method that asks a views nested textfield to resign. Sound handy? It is. By calling it on the tableview the textfield it contains resigns first responder. Since this technique works on all `UIView`s there is no need to artificially limit this outlet to only `UITableView`s so the outlet is just `UIView *mainView`.

The final moving part here is the `UITapGestureRecognizer`. We don't want to add this recognizer full time for fear of screwing up the tableview's workings. So we take advantage of `UIView`'s delegate method `didMoveToWindow`. We don't really do anything with the window we just check to see if we are in one; If we are then one of our textfields is first responder, if not then it's not. We add and remove our gesture recognizer accordingly.

Okay straightforward enough, but how do you use it? Well if instantiating in code you could do it like this, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 6, 100, 31)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:field];
    field.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    field.inputAccessoryView = [[NJ_KeyboardDismisser alloc] initWithMainView:self.view];
}
```

If you are using static cells in a storyboard then the technique is different (obviously). First drag out a generic `NSObject` and place it in the dark grey strip below the view (where the other objects such as the view controller are). Then change this new object's class to be `NJ_KeyboardDismisser`. Then connect the "Keyboard Dismisser"'s `mainView` property to that view (generally a tableview). Then connect the `inputAccessoryView` property from any each text field in that scene you wish to the "Keyboard Dismisser".

[image: Image of the Keyboard Dismisser object listed among the other view controller objects.]

Give it a try! The tableview acts normally. Apple's tap recognizer is smart enough to ignore the swipes on the table, so you can scroll. It also ignores touches in the textfields so you can edit and select other textfields. But tap outside a textfield and the keyboard is gone.

**Note:** This class's use is not limited to tableviews. If you want to use it on a regular view, just set the `mainView` property to be the same as the view controller's view.

Comment: THIS IS BRILLIANT AND WORKS! I don't even know what to do with myself I'm so happy.

Comment: I have static cells of grouped tableview, so i don't need to override `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Now where should I place second snippet of code???

Comment: @mohsin.mr I added to my answer to address the growing use of storyboards. I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to do this in your view controller:

```
[self.view endEditing: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resign the responder inside the below function for your view:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Make sure your view is enabled for user interaction.

Comment: I tried that (and checked to make sure the view is enabled for user interaction), and nothing happens. The UITextField is in a table.

Comment: If it is in a tableview then the base scroll view will take all your touches. What else does the view contain other than table view?

Answer (score 0):

**when creating the text field add a tag to it.**

like this `Yourtextfield.tag = 1`;

and in you `touchesEnded` method

**do this** :

```
UITextField *resignTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[resignTextField resignFirstResponder];
```