# Dismiss a UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad in a UITextField when VoiceOver is active?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, voiceover, uikeyboardtype

How do I dismiss a `UITextField` with keyboard type `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`? The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246509/how-to-dismiss-uikeyboardtypenumberpad) suggests to either add a bar with a dismiss button as an `inputAccessoryView` or to listen to touch events on the background.

I prefer the second approach, i.e. listen to touch events on the view containing the `UITextField`. However, this approach fails if VoiceOver is active. How do you `resignFirstResponder` in that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an alternative way to perform the gesture.  You'll have to add a button to your layout.  Sorry...

You should be able to check whether VoiceOver is on or not.

```
BOOL UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning();
```

You could also consider adding a tap recognizer to an invisible UI Element or a parent View that is completely covered with other elements.  In this way, it would only be able to be activated by a VoiceOver user.

Comment: JFI: I think I will choose the invisible UI element approach. Minor suggestion regarding your wording: I need to add a the UI element not with a tap recognizer but with an override of `accessibilityActivate`. In addition, I need to use both the method you suggest and to listen to notifications `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged`. Unfortunately, it seems to be a little bit complicated, but your answer confirms that there was no trivial oversight on my part ...